Operators that preserve RKHSness?
Are there any results on operators that preserve the reproducing property?
As an example, orthogonal projection preserves this property (and maps the reproducing kernel to the reproducing kernel as a bonus!), while synthesis does not.
Orthogonal projection from an RKHS $\mathcal{H}$ to a (Hilbert) subspace $\mathcal{H}_0 \subsetneq \mathcal{H}$ certainly maps RKHSs to RKHSs and, indeed, gives us an easy way to find the reproducing kernel of $\mathcal{H}_0$: for any $x\in\mathcal{X}$, the representation of evaluation $k_x\in\mathcal{H}$ can be written $k_x = \mathrm{P}_{\mathcal{H}_0}k_x + \mathrm{P}_{\mathcal{H}_0^\perp}k_x$. For any $x\in\mathcal{X}$ and $f\in\mathcal{H}_0$, we have that $f = \mathrm{P}_{\mathcal{H}_0}f$, and since $\mathrm{P}^2_{\mathcal{H}_0} = \mathrm{P}_{\mathcal{H}_0} = \mathrm{P}^\ast_{\mathcal{H}_0}$,
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \langle f, k_x\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} = \left\langle \mathrm{P}_{\mathcal{H}_0} f,  k_x\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} =  \left\langle \mathrm{P}_{\mathcal{H}_0}^2 f,  k_x\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \\
&=  \left\langle \mathrm{P}_{\mathcal{H}_0} f,  \mathrm{P}_{\mathcal{H}_0} k_x\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} =  \left\langle \mathrm{P}_{\mathcal{H}_0} f,  \mathrm{P}_{\mathcal{H}_0} k_x\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_0} =  \left\langle f,  \mathrm{P}_{\mathcal{H}_0} k_x\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_0},
\end{align*}
so that  $\mathrm{P}_{\mathcal{H}_0} k_x$ is the Riesz representation of evaluation at $x$.
On the other hand, the canonical between $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ to $\ell^2$ (i.e., the analysis map from a function to its Fourier coefficients on, say, a Hermite basis, and the synthesis adjoint) do not preserve RKHSness: $\ell^2$ is an RKHS but it synthesizes the equivalence classes of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, which is not an RKHS.

What exactly is your question? Of course, the image of the mapping must be a function space again ($L^2$ contains equivalence classes of functions and no functions). More generally, every separable Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to a $\ell^2$-space, according to Fischer-Riesz, but not every separable Hilbert space is an RKHS. So you have to make sure that your domain contains functions again.

Are there operators that map Hilbert spaces of functions whose evaluation functional is continuous to Hilbert spaces of functions whose evaluation functional is continuous? As an example, synthesis does not do this; orthogonal projection does. Are there any general results?

Even the Fourier transform does not preserve RKHSness: the Paley-Wiener space of finite-energy bandlimited functions is RKHS, but the space of their Fourier transforms is the space of finite-energy signals on the compact support is not.
